# AngularJS http post to PHP program using Json array

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am working with AngularJS and trying to post params to a php program so the php program can do a select with one or more variables.

I need to pass a json array which is my sql bind variables,its the where_clause below.

This is the Main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<style>
table, th , td  {
border: 1px solid grey;
    border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http)
               {
               var req = {
               method: 'POST',url: 'angular_master.php',
               headers: {
               'Content-Type': undefined
               },
               params: { what_to_do: "angular_users6", where_clause: '[{"sqlvalue1":"searchvalue1","sqlvalue2":"searchvalue2"}]'}
               }

               $http(req).then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
               });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is part of the angular_master.php

```
if ($what_to_do == "angular_users6")
    {
        $json = $where_clause;


        $where_array = json_decode($json,true);


        error_log("\n where_clause_json : " . print_R($json,TRUE) ,3,$filename_master);
        error_log("\n where_clause_array: " . print_R($where_array,TRUE) ,3,$filename_master);

        $sqlvalue1 = "";
        $sqlvalue2 = "";
        foreach($where_array as $rows)
        {
            $sqlvalue1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $rows['sqlvalue1']) ;
            $sqlvalue2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $rows['sqlvalue2']);

        }
        error_log("\n  where_array: " . $sqlvalue1 . " " . $sqlvalue2 ,3,$filename_master);
```

I get the following in the log that I trap
LOG:

```
where_clause_json : [{"sqlvalue1":"searchvalue1","sqlvalue2":"searchvalue2"}]
 where_clause_array: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sqlvalue1] => searchvalue1
            [sqlvalue2] => searchvalue2
        )

)

  where_array:
```

The problem is the last echo statement  "where_array:" (the line above this line does not show the values of sqlvalue1 and sqlvalue2 , although the print_R echoes show the values.

Since the where_clause that is passed may contain more than one values , why is the last echo where_array blank.

Answer (score 0):

seems that your foreach is wrong. The format of where_arrays is that :

where_arrays = [["sqlvalue1" => webcastpoa@thepentecostals.org, "sqlvalue2" => na]].

try foreach($where_array[0] as $rows)